# interface not matching data

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, next.js

I keep getting this error `Type '({ name: string; href: string; icon: IconDefinition; } | { name: string; href: string; icon: IconDefinition; childs: { name: string; href: string; icon: IconDefinition; }[]; })[]' is missing the following properties from type 'navigationItem': name, href, icon, childsts(2739)`

but I don't get why.

this are my interface

```
interface navigationItem {
  name: string;
  href: string;
  icon: IconDefinition;
  childs?: dropdown[];
}[]
interface dropdown {
  name: string;
  href: string;
  icon: IconDefinition;
}
```

and some data for it

```
 const navItems: navigationItem = [
    { name: "Calendar", href: "/", icon: faBars },
    { name: "Team", href: "/", icon: faBars },
    {
      name: "Projects",
      href: "/",
      icon: faBars,
      childs: [
        { name: "Accueil", href: "/", icon: faBars },
        { name: "Accueil", href: "/", icon: faBars },
      ],
    },
  ];
```

if someone sees what I did wrong pleas feel free to tell me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be the wrong placement of `[]`

remove the last `[]` from interface

```js
interface navigationItem {
  name: string;
  href: string;
  icon: IconDefinition;
  childs?: dropdown[];
} // no need to add [] here
```

add the `[]` in `navigationItem` type

```js
const navItems: navigationItem[] = [ // add [] here
    { name: "Calendar", href: "/", icon: faBars },
    { name: "Team", href: "/", icon: faBars },
    {
      name: "Projects",
      href: "/",
      icon: faBars,
      childs: [
        { name: "Accueil", href: "/", icon: faBars },
        { name: "Accueil", href: "/", icon: faBars },
      ],
    },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need remove []:

```
interface navigationItem {
  name: string;
  href: string;
  icon: IconDefinition;
  childs?: dropdown[];
}// this []
```

and add navigationItem[] to:

```
const navItems: navigationItem[] = {...}
```

[CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-bird-4ml05?file=/src/App.tsx:251-285)

Comment: thx a lot, I always forget to specify that is an array